# Разреженные матрицы

Tags: алгоритм, оптимизация, матрицы

Тема довольно обширная, имеется ряд широко распространённых схем их хранения и множество алгоритмов решения в зависимости от конкретных целей.
Литературы много, но всё подряд разбирать уйдёт год, а то и не один. Нужна именно оптимизация по скорости для довольно конкретного вида матриц и очень ограниченных действий с ними. Может кто из присутствующих тут разбирается в данной теме не по наслышке и может помочь сориентироваться?

Имеются большие матрицы, разреженные (меньше 1% не нулевых элементов), с главной диагональю, симметричные, содержат только 0 и 1, все очень похожие, изображения примеров: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWz3a.jpg

Это маленькие, будут до 150000 порядка
Похожие на ленточные, решение которых сводится к секундам, но есть мусор вокруг, не знаю можно ли их к ленточным привести или в этом нет смысла и есть другие методы для данной проблемы? 
Мне нужно алгоритм придумать для программки для их решения. Пока реализовал решения СЛАУ методом Гаусса, оптимизировал под 64бит с учётом булевых переменных (хранение в виде бит для более быстрых операций умножения и сложения). В результате получилось 50.041 x 50.041, имеющая 0.73% не нулевых элементов, решается примерно 10 мин, что не правильно и ясно что нужно менять логику, а не оптимизировать дальше. Подсказали про разреженные матрицы и данная тема для моего случая очень даже подходит, только не могу определиться какой именно алгоритм для моей задачи наиболее подходит, чтобы не пробовать всё подряд.

Comment: Опишите задачу подробно сразу. Так желающему ответить не нужно будет отмечаться в комментариях и ждать, пока вы дополните вопрос, а вы не получите справедливые минусы за то, что вместо вопроса написали что-то непонятное.

Comment: А еще, грамотно сформулированный вопрос - это уже половина ответа.

Comment: @Алексей Уколов, описал

Comment: Думается, что проще поискать библиотеки под ваш язык типа Intel MKL... https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/520871 Ну и читать и разбираться видимо все равно придется...

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, библиотеки больше заточены под универсальные матрицы, работа с плавающими числами и т.п. Что в данном случае дико жрёт ресурсы, память и в результате даёт не хорошие результаты. Потому написать хотелось бы своё, заточенное под собственные нужды. Потому вопрос теоретический. Конечно, если вы видели библиотеку для работы с разреженными симметричными булевыми матрицами (и желательно для Delphi), то буду очень раз ссылке

Comment: @Isaev, библиотеки могут быть заточены под все, что угодно. Включая разреженные матрицы. И в данном случае библиотечное решение - универсальное, проверенное будет предпочтительней собственного хромого велосипеда. А если таковых библиотек не найдется для Delphi (кто вообще в 2016 использует его?), то стоит задуматься о переходе на современный язык. Например, [python](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) Все по разреженным матрицам отлично гуглится - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix и нет смысла перепечатывать все в ответ.

Comment: @Isaev ссылку я дал, там как раз ваш вариант Band storage, по крайней мере начать смотреть оттуда уже можно. dll'ки к дельфям подключать никто не запрещал. У вас вопрос оптимизации встал, что-то коленочное будет сильно хуже, ну и оно уже...

Comment: @m9_psy, что делает python, появившийся в 1991 году более современным, чем Delphi, который появился в 1995? И давайте не начинать холивар чей язык круче, информатику это должно быть не важно. Вопрос был про теорию и алгоритмы, а не как юзать  стандартные библиотеки и на каких языках. Мне не интересны готовые решения, я хочу написать своё

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, Band storage не мой вариант, что он похож на ленточные я в вопросе и так написал, возможно ли мой вариант к ним привести, есть ли в этом смысл? Это было в моём вопросе. Можете ответить?

Comment: @Yura Ivanov "что-то коленочное будет сильно хуже, ну и оно уже..." Оно 1. если бы все так рассуждали, ничего нового бы вообще не писалось (нужно, как минимум, всегда надеяться, что оно будет лучше... и пока оно хуже будет стимул самосовершенствоваться), 2. от этого будет больше пользы, ибо пользуясь готовым ничему не научишься. 3. "оно не уже", его ещё нет. то что есть совершенно не под то заточено, а для общего случая не факт, что плохо работает )

Comment: @Isaev 1. ваш порыв написать что-то своё и гениальное достоин уважения, но отрицать опыт человечества, надеясь только на себя, как минимум глупо. 2. неверно. 3. как минимум три точки начала исследования вам дали, дальше придется самостоятельно, ну либо у профессора спросить, тут я профессоров не видел...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Тот факт, что матрица изначально заполнена 0 и 1 уже после первого прохода методом Гаусса перестанет работать - получится обычная числовая матрица. В использовании специальных типов смысла нет.
2. При таких порядках метод Гаусса покажет погоду на Марсе, он работает до 10 000.
3. Используйте итерационные методы вроде GMRES или сопряженных градиентов.
4. На чем это дело будет считаться? Персоналка? Сервер? Кластер?

Начните с простейшего = храните для каждой строки массивы пар (индекс, значение). Для итераций GMRES будет удовлетворительно.

Comment: 1. не перестанет, не получится. Ибо используется двоичная арифметика обычные сложение и умножение заменяются операциями сложения по модулю 2 и обработка по 128 значений (MMX) в одной операции...(ответы же тоже только 0 или 1) в результате даже обратный проход не нужен и как следствие: использование специальных типов даёт очень ощутимый плюс. 2. да я уже заметил. 3. спасибо за первый дельный совет. Сопряжённых градиентов показался более подходящим для моей проблемы, но на небольшом количестве процессоров GMRES будет эффективней? 4. целевая персоналка, поиграться могу и на сервере и на кластере.

Comment: Вопрос вдогонку: Как распараллелить итерационный алгоритм? Ведь он по определению на каждой итерации использует результат предыдущей, значит я не могу запустить второй поток, пока нет результата от первого...

Comment: @Isaev надо было написать огромными буквами в вопросе, что работаете в рамках булевой алгебры.

Посмотрите внимательно на постановку алгоритма, что GMRES, что Гаусс - и там и там есть шаг, где все строки матрицы нужно либо скалярно умножить на очередное решение(GMRES) либо сложить с ведущей строкой (Гаусс). Отсюда и пляшем - режем матрицу на горизонтальные ленты и эти ленты отдаем процессору.